# Polymer app-drawer-layout component not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I've initiated my app with the polymer App Drawer Template https://github.com/Polymer/app-drawer-template 
But when I use the option force-narrow in the app-drawer-layout

```
  <app-drawer-layout force-narrow>
```

the drawer works fine but it stops showing me views even though in the navigation bar the pages change, for example it passes from localhost:8081/view1 to localhost:8081/view2

Comment: It's really hard to tell what went wrong. I followed the instructions mentioned in the link and added `force-narrow` to my `app-drawer` and it still worked fine for me. Can you create some snippet, working preferably of your problem

Comment: Please add some more code.